# Strange characters in a page

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

Anyone had encountered the same issue with me?

We had a website and sometimes it displays strange characters like this.

���� JFIF ��C    $.' ",# (7),01444 '9=82<.342��C   2! !22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222�� �� " �� ��� } !1A Qa "q 2��� #B�� R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ��� w !1 AQ aq "2� B����   #3R� br� $4�%� &'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������������������������������������������������������������������� ?���,E�!-� �c��k,¶��B���L�͐�c��q���2{UT���Fw�I�!��XNTg�_׃�Z��-V�UQ��v d�wd0��yⷓI]�$�dk q������!g �< � ���{6;�V���|,�4 �Y[m�{��1��6�� z���궶��= i�%ԋG�� ��b�^�՗;�� ��y=Ȣ���/nK�;L�$xۃ������� ڬï� 鱙�Wi�ɎR Y�8 �� �j��5���Om �6��    ��2� \��ⱌm;�éw+�� l�|ۜ�� � �^ K �������ZO i�� � J� �A �'>� �[�6�y� �Ƥ62 ��6� ~��YkB��^�ki# X��#���·� �kы9�=CU��k�.�1�ܷ�r �q޸� ���Y���"���h0��� ��� :s���jWK

When you refresh the page again , it display correctly. This happens intermittently.

Do you guys have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: wrong mime type? Those characters are a JPEG file

Comment: To help people to find a solution for you, please identify the problem, in this case apparently by URL (and mentioning the browser[s] used may help too).

Answer (score 0):

`JFIF` is the JPEG file interchange format so it looks like it's not recognising JPEG files for some reason, instead trying to render them as text.

That may be a problem with your browser setup though unlikely if it works the second time, or it may be that the wrong MIME type is being sent down.

Time to break out WireShark or some similar tool, to see what's actually coming down the line.

Answer (score 0):

JFIF is a JPEG file interchange. Looks like your trying to render the JPEG as text.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a problem with your encoding.

Use this in your head like this:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
...
</head>
```

it should fix the problem.

also look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html

EDIT: it also could be that it reads the JPEG file as mentioned in the other questions.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer is that "JFIF" (JPEG, joined file interchange format). You are returning an image.

The server answers with header lines, an empty line, and content (the HTML page, or image).

So there is probably a `setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');` or so. Maybe a get_file_contents shown.